# Unable to replace <NA> in pandas with np.nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe like below

```
    Updated_1                       Updated_2
0   <NA>                            <NA>
1   2                               <NA>
2   <NA>                            <NA>
3   <NA>                            5
4   <NA>                            <NA>
5   <NA>                            <NA>
```

Unable to replace  with np.nan. I've used below code

```
df['Updated_1'].replace({'<NA>': np.nan}, inplace = True)
```

But it's not working

Comment: Is your `<NA>` the string `'<NA>'` or the representation of Pandas' `NA` value?

Comment: Right.  The key point is that `np.nan` is a floating point value, and can only be used in a floating point column.  If your column is either strings or integers, then you can't use `np.nan`.

Answer (score 0):

## Step 1 - Reproducing

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Updated_1':['<NA>',2,'<NA>','<NA>','<NA>']})
>>> df
  Updated_1
0      <NA>
1         2
2      <NA>
3      <NA>
4      <NA>
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------     --------------  ----- 
 0   Updated_1  5 non-null      object
```

## Step 2 - Updating columns using OP's method

```
>>> df['Updated_1'].replace({'<NA>': np.nan}, inplace = True)
>>> df
   Updated_1
0        NaN
1        2.0
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   Updated_1  1 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 168.0 bytes
```

### Note -

- Initially the `Updated_1` column was of `object` type containing strings
- After updating the column in step 2 with NANs, the column date type changed to float as rightly pointed by @Tim Roberts